# IBM BlueMix Virtual Machine service is down

Tags: virtual-machine, ibm-cloud

IBM BlueMix provides a beta version of Virtual machines service, I am unable to provision any virtual machine, and every time I get the following error:

```
Your VM is in error - Build of instance 369779a3-b3da-4e0c-9958-491044797e9d aborted: Failed to allocate the network(s), not rescheduling.
```

I get this error using IBM BlueMix portal or even using BlueMix API.

If I tried to restart the VM, I get the following error:

```
Cannot 'reboot' instance 369779a3-b3da-4e0c-9958-491044797e9d while it is in task_state spawning
```

So, I think that there is an error regarding openstack they are using in their datacenters !!

Please do note that this issue raised in `United Kingdom Region`

Does it sound an internal error in IBM services ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are aware of this issue and it is being worked on. Will post a response as soon as it is fixed.

Comment: They are back up and running now. Please try and confirm

Answer (score 0):

I just checked and I get the same error, so it does sound like an issue with IBM services

Answer (score 0):

The service has been up and running. Please mark the answer as accepted if you can access the VMs.